# Is an empty form with a submit button accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I want to break up my form into 3-4 parts. One of these parts is purely informational, so just a description of the data that is needed, with an empty form that has a submit button. Clicking on this button would take you to the next part of the form. Is this going to be accessible? Or should I have a link with a proper title?

Answer (score 0):

As your question currently goes I cannot see a valid use for link inserted into multi-step form flow, so I'd definitely keep **regular form submission** flow even for the *"information only"* step.

After all, proceeding through given step could be interpreted as *"user acknowledged the information"*, what is valid case for the form step submission. So the form step is not "empty", even when there are no form data, the fact that submission happened could be important piece of information.

### When would link instead of form submit of the form make sense?

I tried to imagine scenario for the alternative, and I think that the "skip" link could be used if and only if the **target step is the first mandatory**, because while being linked, the contract goes so it has a stable URL that can be visited directly (anyone could share the URL) provides reasonable content - same content for users who did not went through previous steps, potentially different content for users who did.

Maybe I missed some important detail, but overall -- both from technical and "semantic" point of view -- find submitting form the only valid option.